# Valid, but weird use of yield inside list

Tags: python, python-3.x, generator, yield

I was playing with generators a bit, when I suddenly wrote this piece of code.

Although I have written it, I don't know why it is valid, or why it works.

```
>>> x = (lambda : [(yield 1), (yield 2)])()
>>> next(x)
1
>>> next(x)
2
>>> next(x)
StopIteration
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You created a generator function, with the `lambda` syntax. `yield` is just another expression, so can be used inside a lambda.

You basically did this:

```
def foo():
    return [(yield 1), (yield 2)]

x = foo()
```

but all in a single expression.

Both `yield` expressions return `None`, so the `StopIteration` result value is set to `[None, None]`:

```
>>> x = (lambda : [(yield 1), (yield 2)])()
>>> next(x), next(x)
(1, 2)
>>> try:
...     next(x)
... except StopIteration as si:
...     print(si.value)
...
[None, None]
```

Instead of using `next()`, you could use `generator.send()` to make the `yield` values return something other than `None`:

```
>>> x = (lambda : [(yield 1), (yield 2)])()
>>> next(x)  # advance to first yield
1
>>> x.send(42)   # set return value for first yield, continue to second
2
>>> try:
...     x.send(81)   # set return value for second yield
... except StopIteration as si:
...     print(si.value)
...
[42, 81]
```

It works, because it is legal Python syntax. It's not very useful however.

Comment: I think I understand, but to me, it looks like a way to make more flexible one liner generators: `x = lambda : [[(yield i), (yield i**2)] for i in range(10)])()` or anything like that.

Comment: But it seems its use is soon deprecated if I understand this correctly: "Yield expressions (both yield and yield from clauses) are now deprecated in comprehensions and generator expressions" https://docs.python.org/dev/whatsnew/3.7.html#deprecated

Comment: @HielkeWalinga: No, this is not a list comprehension. Using `list` in a regular list is fine and will not be deprecated.

Comment: @HielkeWalinga: See [yield in list comprehensions and generator expressions](//stackoverflow.com/a/32139977) for an overview of what is being deprecated, and why.